# Application of Gauss's Lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a domain. This is the statement I would like to prove through Gauss's Lemma:

> **Proposition.** Let $f\in A[x]$ be a non-constant, monic polynomial and let $a\in A$. Then $(a, f) = A[x]$ implies that $a$ is a unit in $A$.

My thought is to look at explict equation $ag = fh+1$ and prove by comparing coefficient. The coefficients of $h$ are all divisible by $a$ after comparing and calculating, and finally $ag = af\hat{h} +1$ implies that $ac = 1$ for some $c\in A$.

**How can I use Gauss's Lemma instead to prove the proposition?** Or are there any other results I could use to "wrap up" this coefficient-comparing process?

Comment: you need that A be a domain otherwise the result doesn't hold

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I didn't really use the fact that $A$ is a domain anywhere. Do you have a counterexample when $A$ has zero-divisors? I changed the question body to when $A$ is a domain for now.

Comment: I forgot the fact that $f$ is monic, your method is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss’s Lemma is only for unique factorization domains. Here you can work over $A/(a)$ to get $fh=1$, but $f$ monic and $A/(a)\neq0$ implies $fh$ has degree $\deg f+\deg h$, which is at least one when $f$ is non-constant. So $A/(a)=0$, and hence $A$ is a unit.